# Path tracing: How to do tone mapping and gamma correction?

Tags: pathtracing

I am not sure what is the correct way to do tone mapping and gamma correction in a Monte-Carlo Path Tracer. Should I apply tone mapping before or after averaging the samples?

Comment: Technically, you should apply it after. However, applying it before averaging has an anti-aliasing effect (if you have samples that are too bright compared to the rest). The gamma correction part is only used for more optimal quantization and storage with respect to the human visual system.